# VSCode not parsing inline sourcemaps properly when debugging Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs, source-maps

I'm trying to debug an application in a multi-root project structure ( the root folder containing multiple projects ) and I'm having trouble getting vscode's debugger to recognize the sourcemaps that babel generates.

I have this in my `launch.json`

```js
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "name": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/project/index.js",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/project",
            "restart": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "runtimeArgs": [ "--inspect", "--exec", "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node --config-file ./.babelrc.js", ],
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node"
        }
    ]
}
```

.babelrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  "sourceMaps": "both",
  "presets": [
    [ "@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "source-map-support"
  ],
}
```

and my `index.js` file

```js
require('source-map-support/register')
require('@babel/register');
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('./app.js');
```

When I add a breakpoint, it adds it to another location, when I click on the breakpoint itself, it opens up the compiled file and I see that the breakpoint is at the wrong location. I also see that the sourcemaps have been inlined, but it appears that vscode does not parse them properly, or not parse them at all.

I tried to play around with the settings involving the word sourcemap in their name, none of them seemed to work.

If I open the project the same way in Webstorm and attach to the running process, it parses the sourcemaps properly and stops where necessary, but vscode is unable to do so, for some reason.

I tried to open just this one project in vscode and move the .vscode folder inside of the `project` folder, but it didn't yield any results whatsoever, so I think it is irrelevant, I just decided to mention it if it helps with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up editing the debugging configuration and I got it to work, somehow.

Here's the configurations

The project structure is as follows

```
/root
   /project
```

```js
// .babelrc
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [ "source-map-support" ]
    }
  },
  "presets": [
    [ "@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Debug configuration

```js
{
  "name": "Debug",
  "port": 9229,
  "request": "attach",
  "restart": true,
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/project",
  "skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**",
    "${workspaceFolder}/project"
  ],
  "type": "node"
}
```

And the entry point looks like so

```js
// index.js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    require('source-map-support/register')
}
require('@babel/register');
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('main.js');
```

In order to allow the debugger to attach to this port ( the default port is 9229 ), you need to start the server with the `--inspect` flag.

I use `nodemon` to get it working and this is the script that I use

`nodemon --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229 index.js`

You can use just `--inspect`, as `127.0.0.1:9229` is the default host:port. However, if you are running more than one server on your machine, you will have port collisions, so you'd want to run them on different ports.

If you simultaneously run a client and a server application, you will need to use different ports. Do not forget to set the port accordingly in the `launch.json` file.

```
nodemon --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229 index.js
nodemon --inspect=127.0.0.1:9230 index.js
```

Now, I'm not sure the `source-map-support/register` part is necessary ( though I barely got it to work and don't want to mess with it ).

When using `babel/register`, it transpiles the code at run-time, so the source code should remain intact, which is why source maps are not supposed to be necessary.

I'm using the `attach` mode, because I run the application from an external terminal. If you would like to run a launch configuration, have a look [here for a recipe](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_restarting-debug-sessions-automatically-when-source-is-edited)

**Disclaimer**

Debugging this way without an `outDir`, as I understand it, is rather slow. If you are  working on a smaller project it might not bother you, the time after a save, before the app gets back on its feet is around 10 seconds for me.

I do not know how to get around this with this setup, if you are building your project its supposed to be faster. It might be faster with a `launch` configuration as well.